# Convert xpath(with respect to invoking object) to css

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Following is the element that I located using xpath:

```
element2 = element1.find_element(:xpath, ".//a")
```

xpath is `.//a`

I want to convert it to css. What is equivalent css of it?

Note: `.` is important in `.//a` because I want to find it with respect to `element1`

Similarly, what could be css equivalent of `..//a`

Comment: you do not really require the first element reference to find the second element using xpath. Also a . is not really necessary in xpaths, creates more problems than it helps. If you can share the html I can help you out.

Comment: The things, I mentioned in my questions are simple one and that is only for better understanding of what I want to achieve. Basically, I'm looking for migrating xpaths from my scripts to css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css equivalent for `.//a` is `a` with white-space before it (e.g. `div a` will find all `a` in all `div`s). This will find all elements with tag name `a` on any level inside parent element. For more information you can visit [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

So your code will be the following: `element2 = element1.find_element(:css, " a")`
I don't sure about `:css` because i don't know the language you are using.

Comment: Thanks Evgenity! Could you please me  css for `..//a`? I mean what is for `..`

Comment: Unfortunately there are no equivalent for `../` in css. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: Ok, thanks Evgenity. Accepted your answer since it helped to achieve `.` :)